# How to pass value from an enum selectlist to controller to filter results

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I've created a drop down menu on a web page that needs to filter results loaded from a database by their country. I've created and populated the list from an enum class, which I will provide in the code below. I'm stuck on figuring out how to pass the value selected to the controller so I can perform the filter?

```
//View
@model List<Merchandise>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Variant Summary";
}

<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Variant Summary</h2>
            @Html.DropDownList("Countries", new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Countries))))             
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>

//Model
 public class Merchandise
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        //g.PlanSeqId, g.ItemId, g.ItemDescription, g.OrderQuantity, g.OrderSldTdy, g.PlannedMinutesQty, g.ActualMinutesQty
        public int PlanSeqId { get; set; }
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public string ItemDescription { get; set; }
        public int OrderQuantity { get; set; }
        public int OrderSldTdy { get; set; }
        public int PlannedMinutesQty { get; set; }
        public int ActualMinutesQty { get; set; }
        public Countries Countries { get; set; }
    }

    public enum Countries
    {
        USA, EUR, JPN
    }

//Controller
public IActionResult Merchandise()
        {            
            Countries selCountry = Countries.USA;
            switch (selCountry)
            {
                case Countries.USA:
                    var bucket = _bucketProvider.GetBucket("MerchUSA");
                    var n1ql = @"SELECT META(g).id, g.PlanSeqId, g.ItemId, g.ItemDescription, g.OrderQuantity, g.OrderSldTdy, g.PlannedMinutesQty, g.ActualMinutesQty
                                FROM `MerchUSA` g
                                WHERE g.CompanyId = 0;
                                LIMIT = 20;";
                    var query = QueryRequest.Create(n1ql);
                    var results = bucket.Query<Merchandise>(query);
                    return View(results.Rows);
                case Countries.EUR:
                    var bucket2 = _bucketProvider.GetBucket("MerchEUR");
                    var n1ql2 = @"SELECT META(g).id, g.PlanSeqId, g.ItemId, g.ItemDescription, g.OrderQuantity, g.OrderSldTdy, g.PlannedMinutesQty, g.ActualMinutesQty
                                FROM `MerchEUR` g
                                WHERE g.CompanyId = 1;
                                LIMIT = 20;";
                    var query2 = QueryRequest.Create(n1ql2);
                    var results2 = bucket2.Query<Merchandise>(query2);
                    return View(results2.Rows);
                case Countries.JPN:
                    var bucket3 = _bucketProvider.GetBucket("MerchJPN");
                    var n1ql3 = @"SELECT META(g).id, g.PlanSeqId, g.ItemId, g.ItemDescription, g.OrderQuantity, g.OrderSldTdy, g.PlannedMinutesQty, g.ActualMinutesQty
                                FROM `MerchJPN` g
                                WHERE g.CompanyId = 2;
                                LIMIT = 20;";
                    var query3 = QueryRequest.Create(n1ql3);
                    var results3 = bucket3.Query<Merchandise>(query3);
                    return View(results3.Rows);
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Right now I'm just seeing the dropdown with the countries, but no value is being passed to the controller to filter the results.

Comment: Assign each enum an int value     public enum Countries
    {
        USA = 1, EUR = 2, JPN = 3
    }

dropdown lists usually needs a value associated with the text

Comment: I also noticed youre assigning Countries.USA to selCountry.... are you sure that's what you want to do?

Comment: Do you mean that you are trying to get a value of `Countries` from the web page in the `Merchandise` method? It may also help if you post what your view code.

Comment: Values will not be passed to Action methods without being sent by a request, having a select input doesn't mean it'll send a request to your action method. you may have to put it in a form, or use ajax, It's not clear enough what you really want.

Comment: Sorry this is my first question on this site, bear with me. The view page is going to be showing a list of items for each country (I know the one says EUR), with each field populated from the model class. The data is coming from a couchbase server, so there is no sql database in the program itself. Each country has it's own database call in couchbase, which is shown in the controller. Basically, I'm trying to figure out how to pass selectList values to the controller. Not too familiar with ajax, but was considering jQuery possibly if I knew how to provide an id or class to the Razor code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ammar commented , you should pass the dropdownlist value by a request . Try using ajax to call the `Merchandise` method and sending the selected value with querystring format .

View

```
@Html.DropDownList("Countries", new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Countries))),new  { @id="dropdownlist"})

@section Scripts
{
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#dropdownlist").change(function () {
        var select = $("#dropdownlist").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: "/YourController/Merchandise?select=" + select,
            success: function () {
                alert("ok");
            }
        });
    });
  </script>
}
```

Controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAccommodation(Countries select)
{
        switch (select)
        {
            case Countries.USA:
               // the stuff you want
        }
 }
```

Comment: @bob82, I'm glad to help you , could mark my reply as the answer ? This will help other people who face the same or similar issue . Thanks a lot !